# How to create a copy of mongoose's Aggregate object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need a way to duplicate and dynamically modify my requests to the database. With regular mongoose [Query objects](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js) I can create a copy of the query with `x = query.toConstructor()` and later fire multiple requests with additional parameters, e.g.:

```
var sample = x().limit(5);
var totalCount = x().count();
```

However mongoose's [Aggregate objects](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate-js) lack the `toConstructor` function. Is there any way to achieve same results with an Aggregate object?

Answer (score 1):

The following solution worked for me well, though not so nice.

```
const withoutId = Model.aggregate().project({ _id: false });
const totalCount = Model.aggregate(withoutId.pipeline()).count('count');
```

Hope this will help at least others.